# JavaScript display coordinates of mouse click more than once

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

I am just learning JavaScript at the moment and I have been able to write an event handler for when a user clicks on the document that will output the mouse clicks coordinates.

However the problem I am having is that it will only do it **once**. I thought that if the event handler is waiting for a "click" and if it got one it would evoke the function getCords.

```
var x = document;
x.addEventListener("click", getCords, false);

function getCords(event){
    x.writeln(event.clientX, ",", event.clientY)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.writeln):

> `document.writeln` is the same as `document.write` but adds a newline.

So, [let's look at `document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.write):

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling
>   `document.open()` will automatically perform a document.open call. Once
>   you have finished writing, it is recommended to call `document.close()`,
>   to tell the browser to finish loading the page. The text you write is
>   parsed into the document's structure model. In the example above, the
>   h1 element becomes a node in the document.

What does this mean?

It means that your code *really* looks like this:

```
var x = document;
x.addEventListener("click", getCords, false);

function getCords(event){
    x.open(); // <-------- new
    x.writeln(event.clientX, ",", event.clientY)
}
```

The first fix to make (which will also stop the page appearing as "loading" forever) is to add the `document.close()` call as advised:

```
var x = document;
x.addEventListener("click", getCords, false);

function getCords(event){
    x.open(); // <-------- new
    x.writeln(event.clientX, ",", event.clientY)
    x.close(); // <-------- new
}
```

Now it's clearer what's going on — we're creating a *new* document stream here. Your existing document contents are overwritten; the event handler ceases to exist.

In fact, [the DOM standard says this explicitly about `open`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75233634):

> Open a document stream for writing. **If a document exists in the target, this method clears it.**

And your new document doesn't contain your script, so even re-assigning the event handler inside the callback won't work.

Best not to use `document.write` (and `document.writeln`) at all; assign the text to be the contents of some `div` or `span` node instead.

Comment: perfect! Thanks for the insight! I got it working by using a div! Thanks for your help.